# Is a strictly global minimum a unique global minimum?

Tags: nonlinear-optimization

A strictly global minimum of a nonlinear continuous twice differentiable function seems to imply that this minimum is its unique global minimum. How this can be proved or disproved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define a strict minimum as a point whose value is strictly less than every other point, then by definition it is a unique minimum.